# SAP Cloud Platform Cockpit Git Repository is missing and gives 500 error

Tags: git, sap-cloud-platform

I have been working on several Fiori applications using SAP Web IDE, And it was working fine until last week. I've done `commits`, `Pulls`, and `Pushs` perfectly from web IDE to the Git repository for multiple applications.

But when I try to check the Git repository from the SAP Cloud Platform Cockpit today, can view all the other repositories except one.

And it says

> HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

[image]

I clicked the Repository Browser link from the following screen

[image]

And It shows a Disk Usage also. But I cannot view the repository or, do `Pull`, `Push`, `Clone` or anything from the Web IDE.

I didn't do anything (deleting) to the repository. Only did `commit` and `push`.
And also there weren't any conflicts since I was the only person who was working on the application.

It happens only for this application. Other application repositories are fine.

Comment: Do you still get this HTTP 500 error? Maybe it was just a temporary issue?

Comment: Now I can view the repository browser. But cannot push using OLD web IDE. It shows an error saying invalid location
I migrated my app to full-stack web ide and now able to push to the repository